# Build React Native Android App, But the Debug App Still Trying to Find Old File

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, native

I build a new app, but strangely whenever I compiled the app and run it on my device, it still tried to use some old files from other project

[error details in orange box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmh5i.png)

[Screengrab from the device, notice the Duravinyl folder, not Duravinyl Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6m8J.png)

As you can see, it tried to use module from my old project (folder is E:/Duravinyl)
The new project is completely new (folder is E:/Duravinyl Android)

I tried clear gradle, rebuild everything, etc
but still the app try to load module from other project

Any help?

Comment: A good first step would be to remove the `node_modules` folder and reinstall using npm or yarn and see if that clears things up.

Comment: already tried, problem stil persist